# Closed algebraic subset dominating a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

In the book "C. Voisin. Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry. Volume II. Cambridge
studies in advanced mathematics 76 (2002)" page 228 says:

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. If $C$ is a smooth curve and  $Z\subset C\times X$ a closed algebraic subset of codimension $r$ of $X$ each of whose components dominates $C$...

I think the phrase "each of whose components dominates $C$" means that there is a dominant map from each component of $Z$ to $C$, but I am not sure. I would like to know is I am rigth, if not, I would like to know what this phrase mean.

Comment: The natural interpretation would be that the restriction to each component of $Z$ of the projection map $Z \to C$ is dominant.

Comment: @auniket thank you :)!